# why extend's class insert before inheritance chain when use extend?

Tags: ruby, class

When i use B extend A ,A is the first in B's single instance's inheritance chain . Where is B ? Why A is the first ?

```
module A

end

class B
  extend A

  class << self 
    p self ##<Class:B>   
    p self.ancestors #[A, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
  end  
end
```

My ruby version is

```
C:\Users\wb-hetiezheng>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [i386-mingw32]
```

Comment: Why should `B` be in this chain? It's not parent of itself.

Comment: The document say "Returns a list of modules included in mod (including mod itself)." .http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors

Comment: `B` is class not module

Comment: `B.singleton_class.ancestors #=> [#<Class:B>, A, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`. See `A`?

Comment: You are right . But why self cannot get the same result ? It is also B.singleton_class .

Comment: @dimakura `B` should be in the chain, because that's the documented behavior of `Module#ancestors`.

Comment: @dimakura, `  B.is_a? Class #=> true; B.is_a? Module #=> true; A.is_a? Module #=> true; A.is_a? Class #=> false`.

Comment: @zealoushacker, Cary thanks. The answer also made it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in `ruby 2.0.0p645`, because I get the following output at that patch level as well:

`[A, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

```
2.0.0-p645 :001 > module A
2.0.0-p645 :002?>   end
 => nil
2.0.0-p645 :003 > class B
2.0.0-p645 :004?>   extend A
2.0.0-p645 :005?>   class << self
2.0.0-p645 :006?>     p self
2.0.0-p645 :007?>     p self.ancestors
2.0.0-p645 :008?>     end
2.0.0-p645 :009?>   end
#<Class:B>
[A, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
 => [A, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

This certainly just worked fine for me with `ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]` via `pry`:

```
pry
[1] pry(main)> module A
[1] pry(main)* end
nil
=>
[2] pry(main)> class B
[2] pry(main)*   extend A
[2] pry(main)*
[2] pry(main)*   class << self
[2] pry(main)*     p self
[2] pry(main)*     p self.ancestors
[2] pry(main)*   end
[2] pry(main)* end
#<Class:B>
[#<Class:B>, A, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
[
    [0] #<Class:B> < #<Class:Object>,
    [1] A,
    [2] #<Class:Object> < #<Class:BasicObject>,
    [3] #<Class:BasicObject> < Class,
    [4] Class < Module,
    [5] Module < Object,
    [6] Object < BasicObject,
    [7] PP::ObjectMixin,
    [8] Kernel,
    [9] BasicObject
]
=>
```

It also worked just fine in `irb`:

```
2.1.0 :001 > module A
2.1.0 :002?>   end
 => nil
2.1.0 :003 > class B
2.1.0 :004?>   extend A
2.1.0 :005?>
2.1.0 :006 >     class << self
2.1.0 :007?>     p self
2.1.0 :008?>     p self.ancestors
2.1.0 :009?>     end
2.1.0 :010?>   end
#<Class:B>
[#<Class:B>, A, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
 => [#<Class:B>, A, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
2.1.0 :011 >
```

I've also tested this with a simple `.rb` file called `module_ancestors.rb`:

```
module A

end

class B
  extend A

  class << self
    p self.ancestors
  end
end
```

Running `$ ruby module_ancestors.rb` produced:

`[#<Class:B>, A, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

So yea, you have some sort of issue not with your code, but with your ruby implementation.

Comment: I think you are right . It's ruby implementation problem .  My ruby version is ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [i386-mingw32] . I get the same result what i describe when use irb  .

Comment: I am testing by installing your patch level, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Confirmed! It's your ruby patch level. There must have been some sort of bug in the implementation for `p645`. See my revision.